# Different Fog host for SSL and Non-SSL Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I'm using Carrierwave with Fog for managing uploads in a Rails App. And recently, some pages of the app were changed to be served over HTTPS only. So my Fog Host was changed from

```
config.fog_host = "a%d.cdn.com"
```

to

```
config.fog_host = "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Is it possible to change Carrierwave fog_host to a Proc that takes in a request and decides which fog host to use, just like with Rails asset_host as its described here

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

```
config.fog_host = Proc.new { |req|
  if req.ssl?
    "ssl_asset_host"
  else
    "non_ssl_asset_host"
  end
end
```

How do I go about it?